# Vaadin applicationContext nullpointer error on weblogic server

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, vaadin7, weblogic12c

I have a problem with my vaadin application. The project works successfully my local tomcat server. When I deploy it in a weblogic server I get an error like below. How can I solve this problem?

In addition I have some embedded resources (image files) for a simple user guide.

DBDefaultValues.java:

```
private static void addDefaultCompany() {
  ICompanyService companyService = 
     UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(ICompanyService.class); //line:34
  if (companyService.getCompanies().size() == 0) {
     Company company = new Company();
     company.setCompanyName("MyComapny");
     companyService.save(company);
  }
}
```

UtilsForSpring.java:

```
@Component
public class UtilsForSpring implements ApplicationContextAware {
   private static ApplicationContext context;

   public static <T> T getSingleBeanOfType(Class<T> beanClass) {
       return context.getBeansOfType(beanClass).values().iterator().next();
   }

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        UtilsForSpring.context = context;
   }
}
```

config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.vaadinapp"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/hibernate.properties"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <task:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="clearReservedPstnBbk" class="com.myproject.vaadinapp.MainUI"></bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="suppressClose" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="hibernateCfgProperties"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.validate">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.automaticTestTable">conTestTable</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateCfgProperties"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.vaadinapp.model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

here is error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1474)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1434)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.egemsoft.ahenk.utils.UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(UtilsForSpring.java:17)
    at net.egemsoft.ahenk.utils.DBDefaultValues.addDefaultCompany(DBDefaultValues.java:34)
    at net.egemsoft.ahenk.utils.DBDefaultValues.initialize(DBDefaultValues.java:25)
    at net.egemsoft.ahenk.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:83)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:698)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>
```

Comment: what is your weblogic version?

Comment: my version is 12.1.3

Comment: shouldn't your setApplicationContext be annotated with @autowired?

Comment: also, the weblogic's classloader may be loading the classes in a different order than tomcat. You have to make sure UtilsForSpring is constructed before DBDefaultValues. Try defining the UtilsForSpring bean in your spring configuration xml and make sure it's the first line in the said xml. <bean class="xxx.UtilsForSpring" />

Comment: I added autowired and redeployed, but I am getting same error still.

Comment: My first line is that in the web.xml, by the way It worked successfully before, but now doesn't, <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: I'm talking about your spring config xml. not 'web.xml'. Could you share your spring config xml and define the bean in the xml as I said before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! reason is that I used to a Vaadin add-on. I tried all versions of the add-on, but it is not working clearly with weblogic server 12.1.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechartwrapper</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your DBDefaultValues bean is constructed before UtilsForSpring. You need to force this.

Change your config.xml so that the spring will construct your utility bean first. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <bean class="path.to.UtilsForSpring" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.vaadinapp"/>
```

You can keep using the annotations as before.

If the above works, then you may move on to using @DependsOn annotation on your addDefaultCompany method and remove the newly added bean definition from your config.xml.

```
@DependsOn(value = "utilsForSpring")
private static void addDefaultCompany() {
  ICompanyService companyService = 
     UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(ICompanyService.class); //line:34
  if (companyService.getCompanies().size() == 0) {
     Company company = new Company();
     company.setCompanyName("MyComapny");
     companyService.save(company);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I am getting the same error still. I tried to comment all this method and I deployed my application. It deployed successfully. But I didn't logged on to the application. I think it could occur applicationContext.

Comment: project codes is here https://github.com/ekocbiyik/testDataManagementDemo may be I forget something

Comment: can you debug the code? what exactly is null there? can spring inject the context successfully?

Comment: All of them are work successfully on my local machine, everything is clear. The problem is weblogic i think. Also I found something like below ------>>>> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [zip:/app/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ahenk_domain/servers/ahenk_01/tmp/_WL_user/Ahenk-test-2.0/z8g469/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/hibernate-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Comment: try changing your weblogic.xml to: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>
    <weblogic-version>12.1.3.0.0</weblogic-version>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>javax.xml.*</package-name>
         </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>

I'm having issues whilst cloning your repo because i'm behind a company proxy. will look into that when I have the time

Comment: you can also use the weblogics classloader analysis tool. it's hosted on the same port as your admin server. then you can choose your project on the left menu and then click on 'Analyze conflicts'. try to see if javax.xml package is in that list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146254/discussion-between-emre-turkis-and-enes).